# Rebase onto branch without common ancestor

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a tree that looks as follows:

```
A--B (master)

C (newbase)
```

It contains two branches without common ancestor. Commit `C` is in fact a baseline for A, a guy who was importing it from old control version system just had forgotten to import it.

I would like to rebase branch so it would look as follows:

```
C--A--B
```

I tried

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto newbase A -s recursive -Xtheirs
```

but it results in

```
C--B
```

Comment: I've never rebased the topmost commit ... but try what happens when replacing `A` with `A~1`

Comment: Thats because using an `upstream` in `rebase` the `upstream-commit` itself is not included, so you have to use `git rebase --onto newbase A~ ...`

Comment: I can't because A is the root

Comment: @nkdm just use common rebase command. See my answer. It is not a problem that you rebase onto orphan branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `git rebase --root` (plus whatever additional options you like, in this case your `--onto` and strategy options).

(I have only tested this with interactive rebase, but it is documented as working with all forms of rebase.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just use rebase and then delete `newbase` branch:

```
git checkout master
git rebase newbase
```